# Styling a Chart within a Popup

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I have a dojox bar chart on my app, that is populated from a QueryTask everytime the extent changes.

[image]

I am making use of the Tufte theme (the only one that has a transparent background), and overriding the bar colours/outlines when i populate the chart:

```
chart1.setTheme(dojox.charting.themes.Tufte);
    chart1.addSeries("Languages", [
        { y: pctArabic, fill: "#C23A00", stroke: null, tooltip: ctArabic + " in Arabic },
        { y: pctMalay, fill: "#6BAE11", stroke: null, tooltip: ctMalay + " in Malay" },
        ....
    ]);
    chart1.render();
```

I have also been using [the Esri sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/query_dojochart.html) as a reference, and have successfuly added a popup to my map which shows some totals per suburb in a dojox piechart:

[image]

My codes is identical to the sample, bar the fields have been swapped out.

```
template = new esri.dijit.PopupTemplate({
          title: "Tweet Languages in {SA2_NAME}",
          mediaInfos: [
            {
              type: "piechart",
              value: { 
                fields: [ 
                  "TotArabic", "TotMalay",
                 ....
                ],
                theme: "Tufte"
              }
            }
          ]
        });
```

### My problem:

I need some control over styling the chart within the popup.

**How do I force the pie segments to be specific colours, as per my bar chart example?**

When I look at the API reference for Popup, mediainfos does not look like it has this level of control over the chart?

**How do I override the tooltips with an alias like I did with my bar chart example?**

I will also need to style the popup to have a similar dark grey background to my chart background, but I believe that won't be related to the chart, and should be achievable via styling the popup with CSS.

Answer (score 4):

I would personally create the chart myself rather than trying to use the ESRI popup class and then add it to a simple info window.

Here is a link to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gGrv/30/) which gives the basic idea. I'd based upon ESRI's sample that you sited. I haven't shown how to populate your own data in to the series, it just uses mock data. Let me know if you are not sure how to do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/9gGrv/30/

You may find the [nightly test](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_pie2d.html) build useful

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am going though your fiddle and let you know soon.. thanks a lot once again : )

Comment: Many thanks for this. I updated your example to demonstrate how to read the values from the feature layer - see http://jsfiddle.net/slead/9gGrv/58/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are going to have to create your own theme. This blog post talks about how that is done: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/charting/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this but its not coming on the map. I will share the code on JSFiddle and if you have similar code implemented in ArcGIS JSAPI then please share your code thanks a lot..

Comment: Did you post your jsfiddle?

Comment: my http://jsfiddle.net/Ym3Xm/7/ & I think mediainfos does not support advance utilities