# Show pie-chart values & legend in info-window for AGS_JSAPI 3.4/3.5

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

Currently I am going through [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/query_dojochart.html) example and trying to insert values in pie chart (I have added that screenshot and want to show values & legend in the info window)

I am using ArcGIS Suit 10.1 and ArcGIS JSPAI version 3.5

What I have tried:

-Tried to insert values in media-info but it is not representing in pie-chart.

-Tried this [dojo-example link](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/charting/demo/monthly-sales-moveslice.html)

this is what I am trying to do in info-window :[image: screenshot1]

Any help regarding this will be great

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: Going through similar question & looks like its not possible  : ( http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44790/styling-a-chart-within-a-popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible.  You can put markup in the infotemplate, you could add a div and then programmatically write out your chart or whatever else you want to put in there.  Post some functional code and I can give you more information.

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/infotemplate.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will try this and let you know & I am using popup template not the info-window.

Comment: The same concept show work for the popuptemplate as well.

Comment: working on your link..